# How do add custom class and id to the <a> that is generated from media gallery insert image into post

Tags: images

I want id="fancybox" and rel="photogallery" added to the generated  automatically once it is "inserted into post" from the media gallery.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Justin Tadlock's [Cleaner Gallery](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cleaner-gallery/) plugin can do exactly that and comes with a couple other nice features. It supports 18 gallery scripts, FancyBox included.

Comment: I'm straying away from plugins for this, i just need a function.php fix,i'd prefer to work it into my theme.

Comment: Fair enough. You'll want to look at the `post_gallery` filter then. http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/post_gallery?version=3.3&file=wp-includes/media.php